# superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)

Tags: xetex, footnotes, natbib, superscripts

This example illustrates some conflict between xelatex and natbib- and footnote-generated superscripts.  The semi-colon between distinct citations is not typeset as a superscript, nor is the dagger.  The asterisk, however, looks fine to me.  Any suggestion on how to make these auto-generated superscripts look more normal?

**Update**
Mostly fixed, see second screenshot below.

**Update 2**
Fully fixed!  Alter the MWE below with this code:

```
\DefineFNsymbols*{safestar}{{$*$}{\textdagger}{\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection}
{\textparagraph}{\textbardbl}{$**$}{\textdagger\textdagger}
{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection\textsection}
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}{\textbardbl\textbardbl}}
\setfnsymbol{safestar}
```

This comes [c/o](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.minionpro/51) Achim Blumensath on the MinionPro mailing list, together with [docs](http://mirrors.cicku.me/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf) for the footmisc package.

```
\documentclass[article, a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra} % c/o @wasteofspace, this is the "offending" line
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}

\let\sc\scshape
\let\bf\bfseries
\let\it\itfamily

\setlrmarginsandblock{23mm}{23mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23mm}{198mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setcitestyle{nature}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a nice\footnote{(That is to say, minimal.)}
example.\cite{lenat1976artificial,lenat1984and} Unfortunately, it has
some problems.\footnote{From an aesthetic point of view.}

\bibliography{corneli}{}

\end{document}
```

[Semicolon http://metameso.org/~joe/superscripts.png](http://metameso.org/~joe/superscripts.png)

But if we don't load [xltxtra](http://ctan.org/pkg/xltxtra), then we get this other slightly problematic result:
[Asterisk http://metameso.org/~joe/superscript2.png](http://metameso.org/~joe/superscript2.png)

I guess I can live with the small and over-elevated asterisk.  It looks less bad when it follows a period.

Comment: as a triangulation point, does the [realscripts](http://ctan.org/pkg/realscripts) package help, or make things worse?  fwiw, i can't see any reason that this should happen in footmisc, but your compilation output looks dire on this screen (and my home latex doesn't have xelatex to experiment with...)

Comment: @wasteofspace: That points to a (partial) solution. "The [realscripts] package holds functions that were once parts of the xltxtra package, which now loads realscripts by default."  If I comment out xltxtra above, things are better. The only problem is that now the asterisk is tiny, and too far up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand that the problem is fixed. Nevertheless let me try to explain what this “conflict” is about.

The problem is not `xltxtra` *per se* but the fact the it redefines `\textsuperscript` to use actual superior glyphs. Quoting the manual:

> 2.1 `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript`
>
> These two macros have been redefined to take advantage, if possible,
>   of actual superior or inferior glyphs in the main document font. This
>   is very important for high-quality typesetting

The standard definition of `\textsuperscript` essentially uses `^{}` to create the superscript. Now, when using `\textsuperscript` with `xltxtra` (or superiors directly) and the font doesn't have the character as superior glyph it is replaced with the normal one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
foo%
{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}123,456 * \textdagger} % superior
\textsuperscript{123,456 * \textdagger}% vs standard

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
foo%
{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}123,456 * \textdagger} % superior
\textsuperscript{123,456 * \textdagger}% vs standard

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see from the position of the comma that it is depending on the font if a character is available as superior.

Comment: Note that the `xltxtra` package has the option `[no-sscript]` option which uses the 'LaTeX' definitions of `\textsuperscript` and '\textsubscript`. The `\textsuperscript*` and `\textsubscript*` commands are then defined as the 'regular' `xltxtra` ones.