# LinuxLibertine destroys biblatex's supercite

Tags: biblatex, libertine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/superscripts-with-xelatex-footnotes-natbib)

i want to use `\supercite` with `biblatex`. It works fine, unless I switch to `LinuxLibertine`. The font messes up the 'superscripted' comma and - line.

Btw: I use XeLaTeX.

Picture: 
[image]

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}


% ACTIVATE TO SEE EFFECT
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}



\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{kastenholz,
      author = {Author, A.},
               year = {2001},
                      title = {Alpha},
}
@book{companion,
      author = {Buthor, B.},
               year = {2002},
                      title = {Bravo},
}
@article{augustine,
         author = {Cuthor, C.},
                  year = {2003},
                         title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\let\cite=\supercite
\begin{document}

Note the comma \cite{augustine,companion} and the underline \cite{augustine,companion,kastenholz}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the same problem as in [superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/superscripts-with-xelatex-footnotes-natbib) and it is due to `xltxtra`'s redefinition of `\textsuperscript`

Comment: Don't use xltxtra. Or at least read its document to understand the source of the problem (2.1 \textsuperscript and \textsubscript).

Comment: Ah, thanks that solves it. I still had it loaded as it was included in some xetex tutorial. I guess i just skip it then.

Comment: Compiling your MWE, I don't get the wrong superscript symbols: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aE8aP.png. Do you have all the latest updates for `libertine`? I just updated mine (MiKTeX 2.9) today.

Comment: @doncherry that's curious... I have version 5.3.0 of the fonts installed ([which I believe to be the current release](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=2)) and don't see a superior comma or endash when I compile the code...

Comment: @doncherry Taking a closer look at the image you posted you don't seem to use superiors at all (which _are_ the  source of the problem)

Comment: @cgnieder You're right .. that's probably because for some reason, type 1 fonts were used instead of some OpenType format (`Requested font "Linux Libertine O" at 10.0pt  -> C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertine O.pfb`. That actually explains why I've always had trouble using OpenType features when using `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` .. I instead used `\usepackage{libertineotf}`. I'll look into this a little more and perhaps turn it into a question.

Comment: @bioslime That means: Ignore my first comment `:)` (Using `libertineotf`, I get the same problem that you have.)

Comment: So this is answered, right?

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented: this is an issue with the redefinition of `\textsuperscript`. For a complete explanation see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80028/17484).

In short: `xltxtra` redefines `\textsuperscript` to make use of superscript provided by the OpenType font. This can lead to undesired behaviour.

The easiest solution is not to load the `xltxtra` package. But if you really need `xltxtra` you can use the following:

```
\let\textsuperscriptoriginal\textsuperscript % Save original command
\usepackage{xltxtra}                         % Load package
\let\textsuperscript\textsuperscriptoriginal % Restore original command
```

Comment: BTW: I asked the Libertine developers if they could add a superior comma and they responded positively.

Comment: 10 years down the line, the absence of either a superior comma or period in the Libertine font makes all the rest of the great superior numbers and letters completely useless. I wonder why they have not acted on this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see it with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
...
```

all other packages are installed by `fontspec`itself.