# Footnote mark alignment with italic text

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment, footnotes, luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/superscripts-with-xelatex-footnotes-natbib)

I'm adding a footnote to a sentence that is italicized, and the placement of the footnote mark seemed to be off. I'm guessing this is because footnote places the mark as a superscript, and because italicized text is a bit lower, the vertical alignment is no longer correct. Here's a MWE. I am using LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,14pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\newfontfamily\temp[Ligatures=Rare, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Style=Historic]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\newcommand\tracked[1]{%
  {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2}#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\large{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textit{Utinam tam facile possem vera reperire, quam falsa convincere.}\footnote{Cicero. \textit{de Natura Deorum}, I, 91. [\textit{Trans.}]}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to lower the asterisk a bit? I'm also thinking of making the mark bigger by redefining `\@makefnmark`, so a way to directly control vertical placement would be nice.

EDIT: I just tried my MWE with pdfLaTeX and it works for some reason. I'm using LuaLaTeX with Adobe Caslon Pro.

[image: Result]

Comment: If I had to guess I'd guess that your problem is caused by `xltxtra` and its redefinition of `\textsuperscript` (see [superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/superscripts-with-xelatex-footnotes-natbib))

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize when I posted that this was actually a problem with using LuaLaTeX. Tried the solution posted in the thread linked and it works.