# realscripts changes star in footnote marker

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

Why is the star in the footnote marker different with `realscripts` loaded?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Text.\footnote{Footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond, realscripts}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Text.\footnote{Footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `realscripts` means that real superior glyphs (especially designed for superscripts) are used. Without it superscripts are simply normal glyphs typeset in a smaller font size.

Comment: @clemens Right, I just figured that out. I'm typing up an answer right now ...

Comment: @Sverre be aware of possible traps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/

Comment: @Sverre as to the why: what else would be the purpose of the `realscripts` package?

Comment: @clemens I use `realscripts` for the convenient `\renewcommand\footnotemarkfont{⟨font switch⟩}` command, which allows me to use lining figures as footnote markers, but oldstyle figures in the text.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two stars is that the star you get without `realscripts` is the regular star character `U+002A` in a shrunk version. From the `realscripts` documentation:

> This package will also patch the default LaTeX footnote mechanism to
>   use `\textsuperscript` automatically.

If the font has an alternate glyph for a superscript star, then the superscript star will be used instead. The font `EB Garamond` has such a glyph, called `asterisk.sups`.